# Which logs to check for read only filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, reboot, macbook-pro, read-only

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, and kernel `Linux 4.4.0-104-generic` on a 2015 Macbook Pro.

As I have read here and on google, when the filesystem encounters certain issues it puts itself in read only mode to protect itself. The search function of google and askubuntu returns loads of people who ask how to fix it but it doesn't answer MY question.

You see, I use my computer for a few hours a day and I have to reboot it every 4 days or so because of this issue. One app randomly crashes, or something behaves weirdly and as soon as I notice it : any terminal window tells me that the system is read only and from this point on there is nothing I can do but to shut it down using the power button (the whole computer become unresponsive in a matter of seconds and there is no way to "ask" it to shutdown, I have to use the physical button). After the reboot the system takes longer to boot than normal but ends up fine.

This problem has been going on for about a year or so and I never was able to figure out what was the cause.

**So my question finally is : what logs should I look at to figure out the origin of my system's instability ? Do you have any specific suggestions to help me single out the cause ?**

Thank you :)

Comment: First look at `/var/log/syslog`. Depending on your configuration, there might also be `/var/log/messages`. One ofthe reasons for instability might be a filesystem running full (e.g. `/tmp`), which is cleaned up when rebootet. "After reboot the system takes longer ..." - of course, as you did a hard shutdown so the filesystems have to be checked. I'ld suggest you to modify `/etc/default/grub` to have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"` and then run `sudo update-grub` to see what is going on when booting.

Comment: Have you run a SMART test on your disk to rule out hardware failure?

Comment: `journalctl -b` will show all logs

Comment: @ridgy, you aren't going to see anything in syslog since the disk went read only so that file can no longer be written to.  You need to run `dmesg` to see the kernel messages directly, even if they have not been able to be written to the disk.

Comment: @psusi: Right, after the mount having been flagged "readonly" there will be no more entries. But maybe the reason for that (e.g. disk errors, disks running out of space) will be recorded _before_. And `dmesg`does not help when the system is unresponsive und you have to do a hard reboot.

Comment: @ridgy @user535733 @psusi Alright thanks everyone. I will try to look at `dmesg` the next time it arrives and see if I can figure it out. And after a hard reboot I will look at `messages` and `syslog`.

Comment: @ridgy, the problem that caused the fs to go read only inherently happens in time before the log message can be written to the disk, hence it never is.  The system remains responsive, just certain operations that require write access fail, and running `dmesg` does not so that's how you can still see the messages.  The original question specifically mentions that the terminal is still responsive and that is how he knew it went read-only.

Comment: @ridgy @psusi well the problem happenned again yesterday. I tried to run `dmesg` but it returned something like `input/output error` (sorry, couldn't copy paste it or snap a picture, obviously). Do you have any leads ?